# vue.js How to add class to table row depending on property value

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to add bootstrap classes (success, waning... ) to table rows depending on a propertys (overallStatus) value.

How would i implement this functionallity in the code below?

Thanks in advance!

```
<div id="people" class="col-md-12">      
    <v-client-table :data="tableData" :columns="columns" :options="options"></v-client-table>
</div>   

Vue.use(VueTables.client, {
    perPage: 50, 
    skin: 'table table-condensed'
});

new Vue({
    el: "#people",
    ready: function () { },
    methods: {},
    data: {
        columns: ['deviceType', 'reasonForStatus', 'ip', 'monitorIsOn', 'freeSpace', 'cpuUsage', 'availableRam', 'statusTime'],
        options: {
            dateColumns: ['statusTime'],
            headings: {
                deviceType: 'Device Type',
                ip: 'Device Ip',
                reasonForStatus: 'ReasonForStatus',
                freeSpace: 'Free Space',
                cpuUsage: 'CPU Usage',
                availableRam: 'Available Ram',
                statusTime: 'Log Time'
            },
            templates: {
                deviceType: function (row) {
                    return row == 0 ? "Stander" : "Monitor";
                },
                availableRam: function (row) {
                    return row.availableRam + " mb.";
                },
                freeSpace: function (row) {
                    return row.freeSpace + " %";
                },
                cpuUsage: function (row) {
                    return row.cpuUsage + " %";
                },
            },

        },
        selectedLetter: '',
        tableData: tableItems,
    }
});
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: i know that v-bind:class can be used but in the given markup there is no row tag to use i on as it is created somewhere in the vue framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `v-bind:class` directive (or shorter version `:class`). Take a look at [docs here](http://rc.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html).

Example:

```
data: function () {
  return: {
     error: true,
     errorType: 'alert-error'
  }
}

<template>
  <div class="alert" :class="{ errorType: error }"</div>
</template>

<!-- or static text assignment -->

<template>
  <div class="alert" :class="{ 'alert-error': error }"</div>
</template>
```

This both would result in

```
<div class="alert alert-error"></div>
```

To bind multiple classes at the same time you can do like this:

```
<template>
  <div :class="{ 'class1 class2 class3': error }"</div>
</template>
```

or

```
<template>
  <div :class="['class1', 'class2', error ? 'class3' : 'class4']"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how exactly i can apply this to my table rows)

Comment: @KimBayAndersen inside your `<v-client-table>` component you need to have a logic and apply the style you want. For example `<tr :class="overallStatus"></tr>` or `<tr :class="[ overallStatus === -1 ? 'warning' : 'success' ]"></tr>` or whatever your logic for the right class is.